# I'm more of the setting sun than the rising sun. Who am I? And why?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

- Hi. My name is six letters long.
- My next of kin always wears a pair of socks in the US. Wearing an odd sock is unthinkable to him.
- I'm more of the setting sun than the rising sun. Who doesn't love the setting sun on the horizon?
- I can give you "c" and "b", but don't expect "m" or "p" from me!
- Most of my relatives have some English idioms or expressions associated with them, but I don't. I'm so jealous of them! I feel so sad!
- French people spell my name exactly the same way English-speaking people do. As for the pronunciation, however, well...
- I have this location in California named after me. Cool, huh?
- One of my relatives was the closest friend of Steve Jobs, but Mark Zuckerberg is not an acquaintance of his.
- You may crush my heart, but people will love me all the same.
- I feel out of my element here in Puzzling StackExchange; I'm more of an Ask Ubuntu lady.
- Out of the seven elements (ice, fire, wind, lightning, earth, darkness, and light), I choose fire.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> An Orange

•Hi. My name is made up of six letters.

> Check

•My next of kin always wears a pair of socks in the US. Wearing an odd sock is unthinkable to him.

> I am not so sure on this part.  I think maybe I will say that red is close to orange, so this is referring to the Red Sox (not Red Sock).

•I'm more of the setting sun than the rising sun. Who doesn't love the setting sun on the horizon?

> Color in the setting sun, but it also does appear in the rising sun, especially if a storm is coming...

•I can give you "c" and "b", but don't expect me to give you "m" or "p"!

> Vitamin C and B

•Most of my relatives have some English idioms or expressions associated with them, but I don't. I'm so jealous of them! I feel so sad!

> Other colors generally have sayings that rhyme with them.  All orange has is "nothing rhymes with orange"

•French people spell my name exactly the same way English-speaking people do. As for the pronunciation, however, well...

> The French draw out the g, making it sound similar to "oranj"

•I have this location in California named after me. Cool, huh?

> Orange, CA

•One of my relatives was the close friend of Steve Jobs, but Mark Zuckerberg is not an acquaintance of his.

> Apple

•You may crush my heart, but people will love me all the same.

> You crush an orange to make orange juice.

•I feel out of my element here in Puzzling StackExchange; I'm more of a Ask Ubuntu lady.

> orange color

•Out of the seven elements (ice, fire, wind, lightning, earth, darkness, and light), I choose fire

> based on the color?

Comment: Kudos to you! The second clue was meant to be the hardest to figure out.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's

> Orange

- Hi. My name is made up of six letters.

> Orange is six letters long.

- My next of kin always wears a pair of socks in the US. Wearing an odd sock is unthinkable to him.

> Not sure about this

- I'm more of the setting sun than the rising sun. Who doesn't love the setting sun on the horizon?

> When setting, the sun appears orange, rather than its usual white

- I can give you "c" and "b", but don't expect me to give you "m" or "p"!

> Oranges have vitamin C and B vitamins, but there's no such thing as vitamins M and P

- Most of my relatives have some English idioms or expressions associated with them, but I don't. I'm so jealous of them! I feel so sad!

> Yellow-bellied, green with envy, etc. But nothing for orange.

- French people spell my name exactly the same way English-speaking people do. As for the pronunciation, however, well...

> Orange is orange in French and English. But it is pronounced differently in French.

- I have this location in California named after me. Cool, huh?

> Orange County

- One of my relatives was the close friend of Steve Jobs, but Mark Zuckerberg is not an acquaintance of his.

> Not sure

- You may crush my heart, but people will love me all the same.

> Not sure

- I feel out of my element here in Puzzling StackExchange; I'm more of a Ask Ubuntu lady.

> The Ask Ubuntu site has an orange theme

- Out of the seven elements (ice, fire, wind, lightning, earth, darkness, and light), I choose fire.

> Fire is orange, the other elements listed are not.